# Get rows with common value into lists

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to get the rows according to the values in the "Type of region" column into lists and put these lists into a other data structure (vector or list).
The data looks like this (~700 000 lines):

```
chr CS  CE  CloneName   score   strand  # locs per clone    # capReg alignments Type of region  
chr1    10027684    10028042    clone_11546 1   +   1   1   chr1_10027880_10028380_DNaseI
chr1    10027799    10028157    clone_11547 1   +   1   1   chr1_10027880_10028380_DNaseI
chr1    10027823    10028181    clone_11548 1   -   1   1   chr1_10027880_10028380_DNaseI
chr1    10027841    10028199    clone_11549 1   +   1   1   chr1_10027880_10028380_DNaseI
```

Here's what i tried to do:

```
typeReg=dat[!duplicated(dat$`Type of region`),]

for(i in 1:nrow(typeReg)){
    res[[i]]=dat[dat$`Type of region`==typeReg[i,]$`Type of region`,]
}
```

The for loop took too much time so i tried using an apply:

```
res=apply(typeReg, 1, function(x){
    tmp=dat[dat$`Type of region`==x[9],]
})
```

But it is also long (there are 300 000 unique values in the Type of region column).
Do you have a solution to my problem or is it normal that it's taking this long?

Comment: Sounds like you want `res = split(dat, dat$\`Type of region\`)`

Comment: `apply` is used for row-wise (or column-wise) operations on a matrix. It's not great to use on a data frame (the first thing that happens will be converting your df to a matrix, losing all the class differentiation between columns), and then it will operate row-wise (with your `MAR = 1` argument). You don't want to run a function on each individual row, you want to take subsets, so `apply` isn't really on the right track for this problem.

Comment: I'd also question whether you really need to split the data before whatever your next step is. If you share your goal, there might be a better way than copying this data into a list, then copying it again into some other structure.

Comment: You don't say why you want to do this, but there's a good chance you can avoid it by using `group_by` from the [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) package

Comment: So i have a bunch of other columns in my dataframe which i didn't show since i didn't think i'd be relevant. But basically, i calculated p-values for every line and now i want to have a maximum likelihood estimator for every type of region. So the logical step would be to get the row for every type of region

Comment: You don't need to copy data into new structures to work on subsets of it. Use `dplyr::group_by` or `data.table` to operate on each group within the data frame. 700k records is enough that it doesn't make sense to copy the same data all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so split works but the subsetting doesn't drop levels of the factor i have in my df. So basically for every list the split function created, it brought the 300 000 levels in the original df thus the huge size of the list. The possible solutions are to use the droplevels() function on every list created (not optimal if one list is too big to store in the RAM), use a for loop (this solution is really slow) or to remove the columns that cause a problem which is what i did.

```
res=split(dat[,c(-4,-9)], dat$`Type of region`, drop=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`:

```
type <- as.factor(dat$Type_of_Region)
split(dat, type)
```

But, as stated in the comments, using `dplyr::group_by()` may be a better option depending on what you want to do later.

Comment: I don't think the split method is usable here because the resulting object is 1309 Go (which i find really strange). Though i think this object is what i want according to the doc